# sending email with attachments in sharepoint 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am working on SharePoint 2010. I need to send email with attachments using aspx and c# code.
Anyone have an idea how to do this?

Comment: I've [written a blog post on how to do this with a Sharepoint 2010 Feature](http://johnmcavinue.ie/Blog/Emailing_Documents_as_Attachments_from_Sharepoint_2010). The source code is available to download so it should server as a good starting point for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at: [How to send an e-mail with attachment from SharePoint](http://edwin.vriethoff.net/2007/10/02/how-to-send-an-e-mail-with-attachment-from-sharepoint/)

Although this was originally written for SharePoint 2007, it is still valid for SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 2):

There is a good library of [Useful SharePoint Designer Custom Workflow Activities](http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/) that has a couple of email attachment activities.  You can either install as is, or crack open the source and adapt to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Try http://sharepointstuff.codeplex.com. It will add an activity to sharepoint designer to send email with attachment